# How to limit number of threads within a time period

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, critical-section

A service I am using starts blocking requests after 5 are made within 1 second.

Using Java in Spring I am looking for a way to queue threads in such a way that up to 5 threads can access the critical section within a second and any other threads are queued up and released once there is bandwidth for them to continue.

Currently I've attempted this with a lock but it causes the thread to wait 1/5th of a second always, even if we wouldn't be at the max calls per second without sleeping.

```
    Lock l = new ReentrantLock();
    try {
        l.lock();
      //critical section
   } finally {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(200);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        l.unlock();
    }
```

With this implementation I never exceed the 5 per second but I also cause the response to be delayed by 200 milli after everything is ready to be returned to the user.

I need a solution that only delays threads when a delay is needed. In this case the 6th+ call in a second should be delayed but the first 5 do not need to be delayed. Likewise calls 6-11 could all go through at the same time.

Comment: Try Guava's RateLimiter.

Comment: Why limit per second and not just allow 5 at a time?

Comment: @daniu when one finishes another needs to be let in. If they are finishing very quickly more than 5 could execute in a second. The critical code section above uses a 3rd party api which after 5 calls per second will reject additional calls.

Comment: Once you've made the decision about what to do, you need to release the lock. You can't hold the lock while you do the actual work.

Answer (score 3):

This sort of rate-limiting is quite a common problem in microservice architectures, as it is part of the broader issue of addressing cascading failures. There are many libraries around to deal with this issue, and one of the most widely-used modern ones is called [Resilience4j](https://github.com/resilience4j/resilience4j), which provides a `RateLimiter` implementation. You probably want something pretty close to this:

Create the limiter:

```java
RateLimiterConfig config = RateLimiterConfig.custom()
  .limitRefreshPeriod(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
  .limitForPeriod(5)
  .timeoutDuration(Duration.ofSeconds(4)) //or however long you want to wait before failing
  .build();

// Create registry
RateLimiterRegistry rateLimiterRegistry = RateLimiterRegistry.of(config);

// Use registry
RateLimiter rateLimiter = rateLimiterRegistry
  .rateLimiter("someServiceLimiter", config);
```

Use it:

```java
// Decorate your call to BackendService.doSomething()
CheckedRunnable restrictedCall = RateLimiter
    .decorateCheckedRunnable(rateLimiter, backendService::doSomething);

//Or, you can use an annotation:
@RateLimiter(name = "someServiceLimiter")
public void doSomething() {
    //backend call
}
```

Comment: I added the dependency but for @RateLimiter I'm getting an error that it is not a valid annotation. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: The annotation RateLimiter and the implementation RateLimiter have the same name. So, if you're using both in the same file, you need to specify the entire package of one of them. e.g. `@io.github.resilience4j.ratelimiter.annotation.RateLimiter`

Comment: thanks. I was able to get this to compile but am still able to get the code to execute more than the limitForPeriod. I have this logic in the same class that contains the critical section. Is there somewhere else the config should be? I saw in the documentation they put it in the yaml but that wasn't compiling for me

Comment: Are you using `io.github.resilience4j:resilience4j-spring-boot2` dependency? If you're still having trouble, you might want to use the approach without annotations.

Answer (score 0):

I think solving it using [semaphore](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)) API would be the best approach.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Queue;
import java.util.concurrent.*;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.Lock;
import java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock;

public class BulkheadSemaphore {

    private Queue<Long> enterQueue = new LinkedList<>();
    private ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    private Semaphore semaphore;

    public BulkheadSemaphore(final Long timeLimit, final int concurrentThreadsLimit) {
        this.semaphore = new Semaphore(concurrentThreadsLimit);

        executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(() -> {
            final Long now = now();

            while (!enterQueue.isEmpty() && now - enterQueue.peek() >= timeLimit) {
                enterQueue.poll();
                semaphore.release();
            }
        }, timeLimit, 200, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    }

    private Long now() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis();
    }

    public void acquire() {
        try {
            semaphore.acquire();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // todo: handle exception
        }
    }

    public void release() {
        semaphore.release();
    }
}
```

The api is quite simple:

1. Each thread entering the critical section, call `bulkheadSemaphore.acqure()`
2. After an external call execution finishes, call `bulkheadSemaphore.release()`

Why does it solve the problem?

- This semaphore releases permits for threads which entered the
  critical section long time ago.
- It releases it's permits at a certain rate (I set it to 200ms, it can be smaller though). It also guarantees that if a work unit has been done quickly, the next thread will be able to start a new work unit.
- Some threads would still face redundant waiting, however it doesn't happen every time and they'd spend 200ms at most.

As requests take time, I'd set `timeLimit` to 1.5 seconds to match your 1 second limitation.

P.S. Don't forget to shutdown executor service